# How to rename files in external hard drive in Mac

Tags: terminal, osx

I am trying to use Terminal to rename my file, but it always says permission denied. I have tried the following:

```
sudo chmod u+wrx test.txt
mv test.txt test2.txt
```

it doesn't work. So, I try to check the details of this file

```
ls -l test.txt
-rwsr--r--@ 1
```

I think it should allow me to rename it.

I am using Seagate Backup Plus Drive, and Mac 10.14

Comment: what does `ls -ld .` say? The name of a file is stored in the directory so you need write permission on the directory rather than the file itself to change the name. What filesystem do you have on the drive?

Comment: You never need `sudo` to do `chmod u+wrx test.txt`. As permission to change permissions is with the owning user. Who owns the directory, and what are the permissions? Please show full, output of `ls -ld .`

Comment: This is the result `drwxrwxr-x  9 root  wheel  646` I guess it is because I use this drive as my time machine backup and encrypt it. Because every time I want to do something with the file I need to enter the password, but terminal even doesn't ask me.